# Linux driver for tplink-wn725n nano wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I have recently installed UBUNTU 12.04 but can not connect to the net as my wireless adapter has no drivers yet. I found some documentation on it, but I am such a noob I don’t know what to do with all this. The adapter is the Linux driver for tplink-wn725n nano wireless adapter

Is there anyone who could explain to me what I have to do with this information? ----https://github.com/liwei/rpi-rtl8188eu.

someone else in another thread mentioned to try:sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic but I dont know how I can do that if my machine is offline. Can any of this stuff be downloaded on one machine and transfered with a USB disk?

Comment: There exist [two](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v1) [versions](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v2) of this USB device. Could you post the output of `lsusb -d 0bda: -vvv` such that the device can get identified? (`0bda` is the vendor ID).

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Comment: Right, then you have the [v2](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v2) device and 81. I see a r8188eu staging driver in at least Ubuntu 14.04 (devel) which runs a 3.13 kernel. The linux-image-generic-lts-saucy package (3.11) does not have this driver. If you wish to update your whole kernel, try http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.6-trusty/

Comment: Downloading and installing the drivers, their dependencies and dependencies of the dependencies will be _very_ difficult without connectivity. It can all be done in a few moments if you can beg or borrow an ethernet connection.

Comment: OK so lets say I get this machine online, can somone please explain how I can get the drivers? One way is update Kernel. I am a BRAND new UBUNTU user, so im not sure what this means. I also know nothing of compiling. Please hold my hand im new!

Answer (score 0):

Install common wifi drivers and wicd network manager.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon
```

Then try to connect with wicd network manager.